# Data from IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings disappears on return from tombstone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

On returning from Tombstone, the data in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings is gone.

Any advice or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Details:

When I try to save into IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings a dictionary that maps STRING keys to OBJECT values, after returning from tombstone, all the values from the isolated storage are gone.  If I don't try to save that dictionary, there are no problems when returning from Tombstone.

Here is the code:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(TestClass))]
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property1 { get; private set; }

    public TestClass(string prop1)
    {
        Property1 = prop1;
    }
}


public static void AddValuesToIsolatedStorage()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key1"] = 1234;
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key2"] = "abcd";

    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dict.Add("the key", new TestClass("a"));

    // IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key3"] = dict;
    // IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

What I observed (both on the emulator and on my phone - HTC HD7) is that if the 2 lines remain commented out, when I return from Tombstone, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count returns 2 (expected), and both Key1 and Key2 are present.

However, if I uncomment the two lines, upon returning from tombstone, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count returns 0, and neither Key1, nor Key2, nor Key3 are in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.

Expected: with the two lines uncommented, on returning from tombstone, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count would return 3, and Key1, Key2, and Key3 would be present.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization won't work with readonly properties.

See for instance [this WCF question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494917/60761).