# Controlling object creation when deserializing using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I am using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize/deserialize my object to/from JSON string.  My object contains a `Dictionary<string, string>` data member, and I want to make this dictionary case insensitive after deserialization.  Currently, after `ReadObject`, I manually create a new dictionary explicitly with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, and copy the content to the new dictionary. This looks ugly.  Is there some way to do this more elegantly?  Like controlling the object creation when deserializing?

Answer (score 0):

The data contract serializers are able to serialize and deserialize get-only collection properties as long as the returned collection is pre-allocated.  (This is in contrast with other types of get-only property, which [cannot be serialized directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494917/3744182).)  However, since the constructors of data contract objects are not called, it is necessary to pre-allocate somewhere else, e.g. in an [`OnDeserializing` method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2014/02/05/warning-datacontractserializer-wont-call-your-constructor/), or in the getter itself:

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary;

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if (dictionary == null)
                System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref dictionary, new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), null);
            return dictionary;
        }
        // DO NOT ADD A SET METHOD EVEN IF PRIVATE, it will break data contract serialization.
    }
}
```

The `Dictionary` data member will now be deserialized into your pre-allocated `Dictionary<string, string>` that uses  `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Notes:

- There *cannot* be a set method, **even one that is private**.  If there is, the data contract serializers will construct their own `Dictionary<string, string>` and set it back, ignoring the pre-allocated dictionary.
- Since the default constructors for [collection data contract objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts) *are* called, you could instead subclass `Dictionary<string, TValue>` and set an appropriate comparer in the constructor, e.g. as follows:

  ```
  public class OrdinalIgnoreCaseDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<string, TValue>
  {
      public OrdinalIgnoreCaseDictionary() : base(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class RootObject
  {
      [DataMember]
      public OrdinalIgnoreCaseDictionary<string> Dictionary { get; set; }
  }
  ```