# error after editing Linq to SQL partial class in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

I have class `Session` in my `WCF`, it has been generated from database, but I've made some changes on it using `partial class`.

```
public partial class Session
{
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public int K2
    {
        get { return 42; }
    }
}
```

I've reloaded `Service Reference` in my application, but when I try to download all `Sessions` from `WCF` I got following error:

> $exception
>
> {"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to `http://localhost:60271/CloudService.svc`. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."}
>
> System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException}

For other classes like `Exam` everithing works as always.

### Update

The same with custom generated class:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class YoloClass
{

    private int k = 42;

    public int K
    {
        get { return k; }
    }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public int K2
    {
        get { return 42; }
    } 
}




[OperationContract]
List<YoloClass> GetAllYoloClass();

public List<YoloClass> GetAllYoloClass()
{
    var yololList = new List<YoloClass>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yololList.Add(new YoloClass());
    }
    return yololList;
}
```

On the Server site everytning looks ok, error apears in application immediately after `GetAllYoloClass` in server ends.

### Update

Something is wrong with my properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class YoloClass2
{
    [DataMember]
    public int K { get; set; }
}
```

works fine, but I need access to local private varibales...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my properties. When I've omited `set`, I got this error...

```
[DataContract]
public class YoloClassRO
{
    private int k = 42;

    [DataMember]
    public int K 
    {
        get { return k; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class YoloClassRW
{
    private int k = 42;

    [DataMember]
    public int K
    {
        get { return k; }
        set { k = value; }
    }
}
```

`YoloClassRW` - works

`YoloClassRO` - not

Well described [Exposing readonly DataMember properties without set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873741/wcf-exposing-readonly-datamember-properties-without-set).